# How to exclude class from YAML file?

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I use SnakeYAML to persist data into YAML file.

```
DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
options.setPrettyFlow(true);
options.setAllowReadOnlyProperties(true);
Yaml yml = new Yaml(options);

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);
yml.dump(object, writer);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

When I try to save the result, I get such content

```
!!com.test.yml.User
users:
- {
  name: Bob,
  age: 14
}
- {
  name: John,
  age: 15
}
```

How can I avoid class `!!com.test.yml.User` from the file?

Also I don't want to save null entities. For instance

```
- {
    name: null,
    age: 14
  }
```

should be

```
- {
    age: 14
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Representer representer = new Representer();
representer.addClassTag(com.test.yml.User.class, Tag.MAP);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer);
```

This code says - please use Tag.MAP for the custom class User. Since the MAP tag is implicit, the tag will disappear all together. But to parse it back you have to instruct SnakeYAML how to parse the data into User instance.

Comment: Code examples are often even more useful when accompanied by a bit of explanation.

Comment: The code says - please use Tag.MAP for the custom class User. Since the MAP tag is implicit, the tag will disappear all together. But to parse it back you have to instruct SnakeYAML how to parse the data into User instance.

Comment: how to set DumperOptions (configure format) and Representer (remove class tag) to Yaml constructor?