# snakeyaml how to write an object list back to a yaml file without lines starting with "!!"

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am new to the yaml files.

My snakeyaml code read the following data into an object list, such as `List<Dept> dList`.

```
- code: '003'
  name: ZXY
- code: '001'
  name: X01
- code: '002'
  name: X02
```

after modification/addition, I want to write back to the same yaml file. But the result file is not what I want:

```
!!map
- !!com.report.settings.pojo.Dept
  code: '003'
  name: ZXY
- !!com.report.settings.pojo.Dept
  code: '001'
  name: X01
- !!com.report.settings.pojo.Dept
  code: '002'
  name: X02
- !!com.report.settings.pojo.Dept
  code: '111'
  name: newName
```

I want to keep the file format. I don't need those lines starting with "!!".

**EDIT:**

The Dept class:

```
public class Dept
{
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public Dept()
    {
    }

// getters, setters
}
```

The load method:

```
public static <T> T loadYaml2(Class<? extends Object> theRoot, String filePath)
    {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new ListConstructor<>(theRoot));
        try
        {
            URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filePath);
            InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
            T s = yaml.load(inputStream);
            System.out.println(s);
            return s;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
}}
```

The ListConstructor class is from here: [How to load a list of custom objects with SnakeYaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187845/how-to-load-a-list-of-custom-objects-with-snakeyaml)

The save method: the data passed in is a `List<Dept>`

```
public static boolean saveYaml2(Object data, String filePath)
    {
        final DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
        options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
        options.setPrettyFlow(true);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
        URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filePath);
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(url.getPath()))))
        {
            yaml.dump(data, writer);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {}}
```

I can remove the "!!map" line now.

Comment: some code can be useful

Comment: other than providing a bit of code, it is probably related to the serialization method you are using

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide bean type in snakeyaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246027/how-to-hide-bean-type-in-snakeyaml)

Comment: @Tobias yes! thanks!  Found another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284176/how-to-exclude-class-from-yaml-file